# Can't access CRUD created via gii from url

Tags: php, yii2, crud, yii-extensions, gii

I want to make a todo application with Yii2 Framework. 
I used the Gii plugin and created models, controllers and views. But when I type the address in the address bar to the index of the list 
*error 404* occurs.

My index is on 
http://localhost/basic/web/

I tried all url combinations but still same error. All the files have been created correctly but I still can't locate them.

sitecontroller.php

```
 <?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use app\models\LoginForm;
use app\models\ContactForm;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Displays homepage.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }

    /**
     * Login action.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->goBack();
        }
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Logout action.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();

        return $this->goHome();
    }

    /**
     * Displays contact page.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionContact()
    {
        $model = new ContactForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->contact(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('contactFormSubmitted');

            return $this->refresh();
        }
        return $this->render('contact', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays about page.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionAbout()
    {
        return $this->render('about');
    }
    public function actionSay($message = 'Hello')
    {
        return $this->render('say',['message'=>$message]);
    }
}
```

views/site/index.php

```
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */

$this->title = 'My Yii Application';
?>
<div class="site-index">

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Congratulations!</h1>

        <p class="lead">You have successfully created your Yii-powered application.</p>

        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="http://www.yiiframework.com">Get started with Yii</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="body-content">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <h2>Heading</h2>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
                    dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
                    ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
                    fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>

                <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/">Yii Documentation &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <h2>Heading</h2>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
                    dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
                    ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
                    fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>

                <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/">Yii Forum &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <h2>Heading</h2>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
                    dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
                    ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
                    fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>

                <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="http://www.yiiframework.com/extensions/">Yii Extensions &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show  your  basic\config\web.php   component => urlManager  (if you have it)  ..and show the url you use for call the index ..

Comment: There isnt anything like urlManager in the web.php file. The url for index is  http://localhost/basic/web/index.php

Comment: Then check if you have the code generated with  gii  .. in site controller ?  and the views (index.php) in basic/views/site ?  .. if you have these files please update you question and add SiteController.php and  views/site/index.php code

Comment: Done please check

Comment: try using    http://localhost/basic/index.php?r=site/index

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use prettyUrl yet, you should access http://localhost/basic/web/index.php?r=gii

Comment: I can access gii but cant access the models and CRUD made by it

Comment: you mean cannot find the files? or access via web url?

Comment: The files are present but cant access them via url.

Comment: could you provide your files?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that, in web.php DEVELOPMENT ENVIRONMENT is not commented.

```
    //DEVELOPMENT ENVIRONMENT
if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    ];
}

return $config;
```

then try using :
http://localhost/basic/web/index.php?r=gii

Answer (score 0):

You should be care full when you filling `controller class` field because it is **case sensitive**. Write `app\controllers\...` instead of `app\Controllers\...`.

I think all fields in CRUD Generator form are case sensitive.